# How do I completely reset Windows update in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-update, windows-11

I've already tried all the usual fixes, deleting SoftwareDistribution and system32\catroot2. I even nuked HLKM\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate and my history and my optional updates are still there. It keeps offering me a driver update that won't install. Help.

Comment: Have you tried the Windows Update Troubleshooter? Which driver installation is failing?

Comment: What makes you think performing a Windows Update reset will prevent the driver from being offered to your system?  In any event, how you perform a Windows Update has not actually changed on Windows 11.  How it was accomplished on Windows 11, is the same process, as it was on previous version of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound Your answer is a non sequitur, given that I've already stated that my windows update history does not reset with the usual fixes. Do you have anything constructive to say?

Comment: @harrymc yes I tried the troubleshooter, at this point it isn't about the one update, it's about the fact Windows is hiding the update history somewhere new I don't know about, I even booted into Linux to erase the info and it still magically comes back

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Go to Microsoft Media Creation link and run Repair Install - Keep Everything and that will get you going.

Comment: @user3353209 - Part of the process of resetting Windows Update deleted your Windows Update history. I was willing to further investigate options before your response to me.

Comment: @Ramhound Did you even read my question?

Comment: @user3353209 - I actually just misinterpreted your comment.

Comment: This smells like an X-Y problem. What is your problem? What is the issue you are trying to solve? Please [edit] that into your question. Maybe 'resetting' (whatever you mean by that) is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I also needed to delete C:\ProgramData\USOPrivate and C:\ProgramData\USOShared in addition to C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution and C:\Windows\system32\catroot2

I am very surprised at how hard this answer was to find since so many people claim it works without this!

Answer (score 0):

I understand your frustration with the persistent driver update issue. Here are some additional steps to try:

Use the "Windows Update Troubleshooter" tool to identify and resolve potential problems with the update process.

Make sure your system date and time settings are correct, as incorrect settings can sometimes cause update errors.

Check if the Windows Update service is running and restart it if needed.

Consider checking for driver updates directly from the manufacturer's website and installing them manually.